# Problema para recuperar atributo

Tags: php

necesito recuperar datos del usuario validado que se guarda en $retorno, lo cual funciona porque lo comprobé con un var_dump($retorno), pero cuando quiero volcar los datos de $retorno a un array, los pone nulos. Gracias desde ya.

```
$retorno = Usuarios::validar($user, $pass);

        if ($retorno) {
            $usuario["idusuario"] = $retorno->idusuario;;
            $usuario["nombre"] = $retorno->nombre;
            $usuario["email"] = $retorno->email;

            var_dump($retorno);
            var_dump($usuario);
        }
```

Resultado

```
array(3) { 
   ["idusuario"]=> string(1) "1" 
   ["nombre"]=> string(18) "José" 
   ["email"]=> string(19) "jose@jose.com" 
} 
array(3) { 
   ["idusuario"]=> NULL 
   ["nombre"]=> NULL 
   ["email"]=> NULL 
}
```

Comment: Quita el ñ doble que hay despues del $usuario["idusuario"] = $retorno->idusuario;

Comment: Que tal si antes de asignarle al arreglo los valores lo inicializas a un arreglo como $usuario = [];

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el problema, el error estaba en

```
$usuario["idusuario"] = $retorno->idusuario;
```

pero debía ser

```
$usuario["idusuario"] = $retorno["idusuario"];
```

ya que

```
$retorno = Usuarios::validar($user, $pass);
```

me devuelve un array, no un objeto.

Comment: Eso estaba clarísimo, de hecho, el `var_dump` te decía que era un array, no un objeto. Lo que no entiendo es ¿para qué querías marear el resultado intentando hacer cosas como estas: `$usuario["idusuario"] = $retorno->idusuario;`?

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por comentar, estoy aprendiendo PHP y quizás por eso no lo vi de entrada. Por otra parte, la idea es recuperar un usuario mediante una consulta y adosar a otros a un array para devolver a una App android que los consume.

Comment: Entiendo, pero con que hagas esto: `$retorno = Usuarios::validar($user, $pass);` y luego esto: `return $retorno;`  sería suficiente, no hay por qué seguir manipulando los datos para al fin crear otro array u objeto basados en los mismos datos que ya tienes. Y si lo que necesitas es un objeto en vez de un array entonces creas una función que te devuelva un objeto. O sea, hay que evitar pasos innecesarios que luego no harán otra cosa que consumir recursos y en consecuencia ralentizarán el código y el tiempo de respuesta para el usuario final.

Comment: Entiendo, la parte de performance es muy importante también.